# How get a list of date from an expression in POWER BI DAX

Tags: list, date, powerbi, expression, dax

I am trying to find a way how to get the list of date when i do this expression in **POWER  BI** with **DAX** :

For exemple : **16/11/2025 - 3**

The output should be like this ( the last 3 Dates):

16/11/2024

16/11/2023

16/11/2022

**EDITS:**

I need just some edit about the Output if it possible.

My Inputs:

column1 that contains dates.

Column2 that contains the numbers

1- for exemple when i do this ( column1-Column2) :

```
 10/04/2024 - 1 (Output)=> 10/04/2023
 10/04/2023 - 0 (Output)=> 10/04/2023 ( stay the same) 
 10/04/2026 - 3 (Output)=> 10/04/2025 - 10/04/2024 - 10/04/2023
```

-And is it possible to store the dates in a list or table because i'm gonna use it later in other formula.

Thanks.

Comment: not clear what input looks like  and what do you want  get as output? How do you want to use the result?

Comment: You could easily create your output table using Power Query. But I'm sure someone will come up with a DAX solution.

Comment: Hi! Maybe You should tell us what your final objective is? What you are planning to do with this? You don't need such a date mentality in DAX or BI!

Answer (score 0):

Please Crete a new table (see picture below) and paste this code:

[image: FRE]

```
DateTable =
VAR FixedDate =
    DATE ( 2025, 11, 16 )
VAR PrevDate = FixedDate - 365
VAR TwoYearBack = PrevDate - 366
VAR ThreeYearBack = TwoYearBack - 365
RETURN
    { PrevDate, TwoYearBack, ThreeYearBack }
```

[image: DF]

VERSION_2

A Better solution from @RonRosenfeld:

```
DateTable = 
VAR FixedDate =
    DATE ( 2025, 11, 16 )
VAR PrevDate = DATE(YEAR(FixedDate)-1,MONTH(FixedDate), DAY(FixedDate))
VAR TwoYearBack = DATE(YEAR(PrevDate)-1,MONTH(PrevDate), DAY(PrevDate))
VAR ThreeYearBack = DATE(YEAR(TwoYearBack)-1,MONTH(TwoYearBack), DAY(TwoYearBack))
RETURN
    {PrevDate, TwoYearBack, ThreeYearBack}
```

And Result:

[image: RONROSENFELD]

Comment: Instead of subtracting days, and worrying about leap year, wouldn't it be simpler to subtract years?  eg `PrevDate = DATE(YEAR(FixedDate)-1,MONTH(FixedDate), DAY(FixedDate))`

Comment: Hi @RonRosenfeld! Yes, You're right. What can I say ? 'one mind is better than other. '  I appreciate it! I think you should write your solution in another answer. :)

Comment: Just go ahead and edit your answer.

Comment: For what ? To claim a point I didn't deserve? No! Thanks! Your answer is more efficient! Please write your answer, and justice is established! 

Comment: Anyhow, the OP asked to start with this "expression": `16/11/2025 - 3`.

Comment: @OzanSen It's not a question I would normally answer as it lacks sufficient detail for **me**. My suggestion was based on knowledge of other programming languages, and I am far from knowledgeable in DAX. So, use it or not, as you prefer.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld What you mean by 'lacks sufficient details'? I added also your solution into my answer as VERSION_2. Do me a favour! Just copy it there, and paste as a new solution. It means Other programming languages can have similar logic but different functions; but That's not the issue here! :)

Comment: @OzanSen No indication of the source of the date-number expression. Nothing about what was tried or research done on this problem. No indication of how output should be presented.

Comment: Thanks @OzanSen  for the solution it's really hepful. 

I need just some edit about the Output if it possible. ( check post again )